# TypeScript allowJs and outFile doesn't emit the JS module

Tags: typescript

The following excerpt from the TypeScript 1.8 Release Notes indicates that in the below example, the contents of bar.js should be emitted as a "bar" module in the final bundled output, given my use of allowJs in tsconfig.

The excerpt from [TypeScript 1.8 Release Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html):

> .js files are now allowed as input to tsc. The TypeScript compiler checks the input .js files for syntax errors, and emits valid output based on the --target and --module flags. The output can be combined with other .ts files as well. Source maps are still generated for .js files just like with .ts files.

*tsconfig.json* -- note the `allowJs` and the `outFile` options

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outFile": "built.js"
},
"files": [
    "main.ts"
]
```

}

*main.ts*

```
import * as foo from './foo';
import * as bar from './bar';

foo.run();
bar.run();
```

*foo.ts*

```
export function run() {
    console.log("Foo runnning!");
}
```

*bar.js*

```
export function run() {
    console.log("Bar running!");
}
```

*bar.d.ts*

```
export function run(): void;
```

tsc 1.8.10 emits this output in *built.js* though.  My question is **why isn't the module in bar.js included in the emitted output?**

```
define("foo", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    function run() {
        console.log("Foo runnning!");
    }
    exports.run = run;
});
define("main", ["require", "exports", "foo", './bar'], function (require, exports, foo, bar) {
    "use strict";
    foo.run();
    bar.run();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why isn't the module in bar.js included in the emitted output?

you have provided a .d.ts (bar.d.ts) file for for module "bar". the .d.ts file has more type information, so it is favored than the .js file.

Removing `bar.d.ts` file would allow the compiler to find and  pick up `bar.js` and the output should be what you expect.

in general having files with the same name, but different extensions in the same location is confusion as it messes up with module resolution logic. the compiler will try to find "mod.ts", "mod.tsx", "mod.d.ts", "mod.js", "mod.jsx" in this order.

Comment: In that case I get a compile error that `Property 'run' does not exist on type 'typeof "...[filepath]/bar"'.` -- is it simply true that typing information on JS files through declaration files and bundling said JS files are mutually exclusive?

Comment: that is beuase `bar.js` does not have an export called `run`. it does have a `default` export only.

Comment: change it to `export default function run() {...` and the error should go away.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant for foo.ts and bar.ts to be practically identical in which case this all works as expected as long as I remove bar.d.ts. Thanks!